# Prestashop 1.6.1.4 not stacking discounts and showing wrong price

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, discount, price, discounts

I have a problem with my Prestashop: If a product only have quantity discounts the total price shown in the cart is correct, but when I also apply a category general discount (from Price Rules) that involves a product that also had a quantity discount, the last one overrides the category discount.

In the product template (product.tpl) price is correct (I mean, both discounts are applied, firstly the category discount and then the quantity discount) but in the shopping cart only quantity discount is applied.

Is there a way to achieve stacking of these discounts?

Thank you in advanced!